# VB SQL Insert Query Inserts NULL for all values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-insert, sqldatasource

I'm developing an asp.net application in Visual Web Developer and I am trying to Insert a new row into the database. I currently have an "Insert" row that is in the Footer Template of a GridView. The footer is always visible and I am not sure if this has anything to do with my insert query not working.

My insert query is called in the Gridview RowCommand Event, I have my insert command text on the asp.net side so on the RowCommand Event, I am just declaring my parameters for the Command. When I debug and step through each line of code in the event, All of the Parameters are receiving the correct values but after the insert, when I look in the database, The entire row is NULL.

I'm not able to figure out why it isn't actually inserting the values from the parameters but it is probably just a dumb mistake that i'm overlooking. Here is the row command code

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName.Equals("Insert") Then
        Dim oItem As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Button).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim DateTxt As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DateTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim First As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("FirstTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Last As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("LastTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Product As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ProductTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Description As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DescriptionTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Quantity As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("QuantityTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Phone As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("PhoneTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Email As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("EmailTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Price As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("PriceTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Urgency As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("UrgencyTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Freight As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("FreightTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim PO As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("POTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Vendor As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("VendorTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim Notes As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("NotesTxt"), TextBox).Text
        Dim PickupCustomers As String = DirectCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("PickupCustomerTxt"), TextBox).Text
        'Dim ID As String = GridView1.Rows(oItem.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text

        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Date", DateTxt)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@First", First)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Last", Last)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Product", Product)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Description", Description)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Quantity", Quantity)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Phone", Phone)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Email", Email)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Price", Price)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Urgency", Urgency)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Freight", Freight)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@PO", PO)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Vendor", Vendor)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@Notes", Notes)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@PickupCustomers", PickupCustomers)
        'SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("@ID", ID)
        SqlDataSource1.Insert()
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the asp.net sqldatasource insert query

```
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Special_Orders(Date, First, Last, Product, Description, Quantity, Phone, Email, Price, Urgency, Freight, PO, Vendor, Notes, Ordered, Received, PickedUp, PickupCustomer) VALUES (@Date, @First, @Last, @Product , @Description, @Quantity, @Phone, @Email, @Price, @Urgency, @Freight, @PO, @Vendor , @Notes, 0, 0, 0, @PickupCustomer)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="First" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Last" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Description" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Price" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Urgency" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Freight" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Vendor" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PickupCustomer" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Error. In my code behind I mistyped the PickupCustomer Parameter. Since My query text was in the asp.net side though it wasn't throwing any errors. Once I Programmatically added the query in the code behind it threw an error.